# xml rpc client java without wsdl

Tags: java, xml, rpc

So I have a simple xml-rpc server (xml over http) provided to me to use. But the thing is, the server is not equipped with wsdl. I don't have access to the server code, so I don't know about their implementation of it

How can I develop an xml-rpc client in Java, with no wsdl provided, without using 3rd party library like the [Apache xml-rpc](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/index.html) client?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wsdl is only really useful *with* a 3rd party library, because it helps you generate objects that can be serialized to xml without hand-coding the xml.

If you don't have the wsdl, you must either hand-code each xml message you send and hand-parse each message you receive, or create a set of objects on your own and serialize and deserialize them appropriately.

Comment: are there no Java package inside the j2se that can do that? I only need something simple after all.

Comment: There are serialization libraries, certainly.  But you'll have to build the objects from inspecting the xml that is sent by hand since you don't have the wsdl to tell you what they look like.  And you'll need examples of response data to send back to construct the return objects too.

Answer (score 0):

Wsdl file will only help out, without that you'll be unable to generate client and neither you can test your application. Even if you have connectivity to server.